# How to display multiple accordions open in bootstrap v3.3.7?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7. I am displaying accordion which is working. When the page load first accordion will open. Now when I click on second then the previous one accordion is close that I don't want. I need when the user clicks on accordion which is open that will close.  In short, I have to display multiple accordions open.

This is the example I am using on my code https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

In this, the first accordion is open and if you click on second then it will close the previous open accordion.

I need, On page load first accordion is open and if click on second the opne the second accordion but I don't want to close the previous one.

I am using below code. Would you help me out in this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove data-parent="#accordion"

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check.

Comment: In your snippet, it's working. I need like this only. I need some time to implement with my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple just change `class='collapse'` to `class='collapse in'` in div with class of panel-collapse

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's displaying on the page load all the according to open. I need only first one.

Comment: You asked " In short, I have to display multiple accordions open."

Comment: Yes, But I haven't said on page load. I need on page load it should be displayed only first accordion and if the user clicks on second then that also open but not to close the previous one.

Comment: @user9437856 you just need to remove `in` class from `panel-collapse collapse in` in all the panels where you don't want to show it open on load, BTW @prantasaha has given the correct solution.

Comment: @ShubhamPatwa, I just have only one panel-collapse collapse in which is in the first accordion. If I remove the In then how can I display the first accordion will open? I remove In from the first one accordion and now my all the accordion are showing closed.

Comment: @ShubhamPatwa, Pranta answer is different. I need only one accordion should open on page load which is working from my side. And if the user click on second then second accordion will open but I don't want to close the first one. In the Pranta anser. It display all the accordion open on page load.

Comment: @user9437856 I got your point I added the answer what you required, please check and let me you if you found anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

#accordion {
  border: 1px solid #616161;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#accordion .panel {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#accordion .panel:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#accordion .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

#accordion .panel-title a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #616161;
  text-align: right;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#accordion .panel-title a.collapsed {
  background: #fff;
  color: #616161;
}

#accordion .panel-title a.collapsed:hover {
  background: #a2a2a2;
  color: #fff;
}

#accordion .panel-title a:after,
#accordion .panel-title a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#accordion .panel-title a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\f106";
  color: #616161;
}

#accordion .panel-title a.collapsed:hover:after {
  color: #fff;
}

#accordion .panel-body {
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #888;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->




<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                 Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nisl lorem, dictum id pellentesque at, vestibulum ut arcu. Curabitur erat libero, egestas eu tincidunt ac, rutrum ac justo. Vivamus condimentum laoreet lectus, blandit posuere
                tortor aliquam vitae. Curabitur molestie eros. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                 Collapsible Group Item #2
                            </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nisl lorem, dictum id pellentesque at, vestibulum ut arcu. Curabitur erat libero, egestas eu tincidunt ac, rutrum ac justo. Vivamus condimentum laoreet lectus, blandit posuere
                tortor aliquam vitae. Curabitur molestie eros. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                 Collapsible Group Item #3
                            </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nisl lorem, dictum id pellentesque at, vestibulum ut arcu. Curabitur erat libero, egestas eu tincidunt ac, rutrum ac justo. Vivamus condimentum laoreet lectus, blandit posuere
                tortor aliquam vitae. Curabitur molestie eros. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be good for me if you try with my code. I check your snippet. on page load, all the accordion are showing closed. I need the first one should be open.

Answer (score 0):

> When you don't want any panel to get affected by other panel don't add data-parent and it will work as you require.
>   [check the docs here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#options)
>
> ```html
> <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
> <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
>     <div class="panel panel-default">
>         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
>             <h4 class="panel-title">
>                 <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
>                 Collapsible Group Item #1
>                 </a>
>             </h4>
>         </div>
>         <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
>             <div class="panel-body">
>                 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="panel panel-default">
>         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
>             <h4 class="panel-title">
>                 <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
>                 Collapsible Group Item #2
>                 </a>
>             </h4>
>         </div>
>         <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
>             <div class="panel-body">
>                 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="panel panel-default">
>         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
>             <h4 class="panel-title">
>                 <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
>                 Collapsible Group Item #3
>                 </a>
>             </h4>
>         </div>
>         <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
>             <div class="panel-body">
>                 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia 
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> ```